# iPhone Autolayout UIText suffocation

Tags: autolayout, interface-builder

I know I can fix this programmatically and I know I could set the text to tighten / scale but I would like to know how to get this text to extend organically to a third line on small screens. How can I accomplish that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you need to take care of before your label grows:

1. Make sure the 'number of lines' field in the attributes inspector is set to zero. Setting it zero allows the label to grow depending upon the content it has.
2. If the label is in a container view, make sure you haven't specified the height constraint explicitly on the container view. Since the container view should generate its height from its subviews and the subviews will generate their height from the content they have. Its sort of a chain process that goes on if you have a deeper hierarchy.
3. Make sure there is no sibling view to the container view with an explicit height that might cause your container view to shrink while maintaining its own height. This point may also apply even if your label is not within some container view.

In the image below, the container view(gray one) is bound from three sides allowing it to grow from the bottom.

[image]

Below image shows the constraints applied to the content views of the container. The container is driving its height from its content views.

[image]

Below I have increased the text of the label from a single line to three lines. At this point the label tries to expand horizontally but since the container view is bind with the super view on both sides the label has only one direction left to increase itself. It increases downwards pushing the textfield and button down and since the button is tied with the bottom of the container view it pulls the container view increasing its height.

[image]